# Mocking IBinder.Bind method in Azure function App

Tags: azure, function

I am new to C# . I just want to know whether mocking of IBinder.Bind is possible . I am using moq framework to mock Interfaces. Below is the exception that i get when I run test .

Exception:

System.NotSupportedException: Unsupported expression: x => x.Bind(AirDataTest.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.attribute)
Extension methods (here: BinderExtensions.Bind) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible yes. Here's one example for a Blob Attribute:

```cs
TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("./textwriter.txt");
var mock = new Mock<IBinder>();
mock.Setup(x => x.BindAsync<TextWriter>(It.IsAny<BlobAttribute>(), CancellationToken.None))
    .ReturnsAsync(writer)
    .Verifiable();

var result = (OkResult)await TutorialBinderOutputBinding.Run(request, mock.Object, log);
```

After executing the function, you can verify it as follows:

```cs
var invocation = (BlobAttribute)mock.Invocations[0].Arguments[0];
```